# How can I link an excel cell to a FTSE share price?

Tags: excel

Can anyone suggest resources/libraries/APIs etc for linking the value of a cell in excel with the price of a FTSE share?

All I can think of at the moment is writing code to download (and parse) the information from the web, but is there some plugin already?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/get-external-data-from-a-web-page-HA010218472.aspx) has some information about using Excel to download tabular data from the web.  Then, you could do a lookup using the FTSE code to bring in the share price from the web table.

Basically, you are giving Excel a URL for a page that has the table, and it simply does all the parsing for you.